# Is there a temporal analogue of the four colour map theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

What is the minimum number of colours needed to prevent the same one being used, not just once in adjacent blocks, but also in consecutive time points? That is, when two consecutive time points are overlayed, you still won't see the same colour used in adjacent regions. I understand the answer for 3d is infinite, but I don't know if it's the same for this question?

The reason I ask has to do with drug resistance in infectious diseases. Parasites are usually able to evolve resistance faster than we can find new drugs. But for some diseases we have quite a few drugs that worked quite well until this happened. Furthermore, resistance to drugs is sometimes a compromise that the parasite would "prefer" to do without. That is, if the drug pressure is lifted the population reverts back to the wild-type. If existing drugs could be divided up into regions, such that the same drug is never used in adjacent regions in consecutive time periods, this could maybe slow the spread of resistance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer would still be whatever it is without the time component: take an $n$-coloring of your map, and then alternatively apply and un-apply a transitive permutation of the colors (i.e., one under which no color is sent to itself) with each "time point".

Comment: If I understand right this would still mean the same colour would be used in adjacent blocks over consecutive time points? To help clarify, if two consecutive time points are overlayed, a region must be surrounded be a ring of colours in the next time point that's still different from its current one.

Comment: @isomerase: No, my proposed solution only guarantees that, when a time point is "overlayed" on the previous one, that the color "on top of" a region is different, not that every top surrounding region is also different. But I think it would help if you could edit your question to make this requirement clearer.